# How do I connect to Apache IoTDB Standalone Version 1.0 from a different computer?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I deployed IoTDB on a server and start it in standalone mode, then connect my laptop to IoTDB on the server, but I cannot connect to IoTDB. The error reported that the server port is not open.

Does anyone know how to successfully connect to the computer? And how to connect to the database from another computer if Apache IoTDB 1.0 starts in standalone mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect Apache IoTDB through Cli tool using this following command: `bash sbin/start-cli.sh -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6667 -u root -pw root`, you only need to modify `-h` and `-p` to your local ip address and port number. Then you can delete the data directory and restart the system to connect again, or you can deploy an empty standalone mode server.